# Please help translate handwritten notes

Tags: перевод

Could someone please be kind enough to translate these two handwritten notes.

[image: Note One]
[image: Note two]

It would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

We are not a bulk translation service. Please see [on-topic](https://russian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

To help you with the translation, I've converted handwritten notes into the following text:

> Я забочусь о своем здоровье: соблюдаю питьевой режим, ем полезную пищу.
>   Я забочусь о своем отдыхе: читаю, гуляю, хожу в кино, театры, музеи и на выставки, вышиваю, выжигаю по дереву, шью, создаю украшения и подарки своими руками, путешествую.
>
> Я занимаюсь любимым делом: принимаю активное участие в организации и проведении мероприятий. Я организую мероприятия как лидер.
>   Моя деятельность приносит мне достойное вознаграждение: более 28000 фунтов в год.
>   Моя деятельность благостна для меня и процветания рода!